# Need to combine these two javascripts

Tags: javascript

I would like to run both of these scripts..

```
var myScroll;
function loaded() {
    myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', { scrollbarClass: 'myScrollbar' });
}

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);
```

I want to add this below in addition to what is above.

```
var myScroll;   

function loaded() {
myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', {
    snap: true,
    momentum: false,
    hScrollbar: false,
    onScrollEnd: function () {
        document.querySelector('#indicator > li.active').className = '';
        document.querySelector('#indicator > li:nth-child(' + (this.currPageX+1) + ')').className = 'active';
    }
 });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);
```

Comment: And what happens when you combine them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create two variables with the same name, or two functions with the same name - not in the same scope, anyway. But you can combine the bodies of your two `loaded()` functions into a single function. (Or you can rename them `loaded1` and `loaded2` and call them individually, but I wouldn't do that.)

I don't know what the `myScroll` variable is used for - in the code you've shown it is assigned a value but never used. If you don't ever use it just remove it (and call `new iScroll();` directly without assigning the return value to anything. If you do use it you'll have to rename one or both variables so they don't clash.

So:

```
var myScroll1,
    myScroll2;

// combined function
function loaded() {
    // statement from the first function
    myScroll1 = new iScroll('wrapper', { scrollbarClass: 'myScrollbar' });

    // statement from the second function
    myScroll2 = new iScroll('wrapper', {
       snap: true,
       momentum: false,
       hScrollbar: false,
       onScrollEnd: function () {
           document.querySelector('#indicator > li.active').className = '';
           document.querySelector('#indicator > li:nth-child(' +
                       (this.currPageX+1) + ')').className = 'active';
       }
   });  
}

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);
```

Comment: Thanks!  I am new to javascript and appreciate the help.